# Calendar directive animation on model change. Problems with digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, refresh, directive, digest

It's my first project with angular and I have problems to understand the digest cycle of the system.

My problem is the following.

I created a month calendar directive. The days are showed with a ng-repeat that iterate on a  list variable called scope.days.

```
<div class="month-calendar>
    <div class="month-calendar-month">{{month}}</div>

    <div class="month-calendar-daysweek" ng-repeat="dayweek in daysweek">{{dayweek}}</div>

    <div class="month-calendar-day" ng-repeat="day in days">{{day}}</div>

    <div class="month-calendar-nav-prev" ng-click="previousMonth()"</div>
    <div class="month-calendar-nav-current" ng-click="currentMonth()"</div>
    <div class="month-calendar-nav-next" ng-click="nextMonth()"</div>
</div>
```

The calendar is correctly built because I have each days inline block and with a percentage of 1/7 * 100%.

When I call one of the functions previousMonth(), currentMonth() or nextMonth(), I generate the new month by reseting scope.days and updating with the new values.

What I want is add a slide effect on the month change. If I click the next month, the old will slide left out and the new one will slide left in. If I click on previous, the slide will be with right direction.

So I added the variable scope.slideDirection that can handle "left" or "right" and that is bound to the ng-class of the parent div month-calendar.

Finally to add the animation I added the ngAnimate module, I added a variable scope.showCalendar that is a boolean and that is bound to the ng-show of the parent div month-calendar as well.

With css, I have the classes that I styled with correct animations

```
.month-calendar.left.ng-hide-add
.month-calendar.left.ng-hide-remove
.month-calendar.right.ng-hide-add
.month-calendar.right.ng-hide-remove
```

Now the problem is in my function that change the month.
I would like to have this for the nextMonth

```
scope.slideDirection = "left";
scope.showCalendar = false;
scope.generateNextMonth();
scope.showCalendar = true;
```

The problem is that the digest cycle is launched at the end of instructions and direction is not set when the transition occurs. Moreover, the transition has not enough time to launch because the boolean is toggle true immediatly after false.

Here is a solution that I wrote but it seems to be running several digest cycles and I may not be the correct way to do that. It's very slow on mobile devices.

```
scope.slideDirection = "left";

$timeout(function() {

    $timeout(function() {
        scope.showCalendar = false;
    }, 0);

    $timeout(function() {
        scope.generateNextMonth();
    }, 300);

    $timeout(function() {
        scope.showCalendar = true;
    }, 300);
}, 0);
```

If someone has an idea and know what is the perfect way to do it, it would be great.

Thanks

**EDIT**

**Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/loric/mDVgX/35/)**

In the fiddle, I set the transition to an opacity 0 or 1 instead of a slide. (just to simplify). And the animation is not run correctly every time. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it you are changing the "showCalendar" value within the same digest loop, causing Angular to really not do anything with it.

Though it is not clear to me why you need to change the "showCalendar" value you should be okay with just one timeout:

```
scope.slideDirection = "left";
scope.showCalendar = false;
scope.generateNextMonth();
$timeout(function() {
  scope.showCalendar = true;
}, 300);
```

It will help with a fiddle on this :-)

Comment: In fact the slideDirection is not updated directly on the dom so the animation will start with the last slideDirection value... I added a fiddle in my post.